# Get all bound Singletons in Guice

Tags: java, binding, guice

I would like to iterate over all bound objects of Guice container. For example, when I invoke `getInstance` I want to get already created instance of `UserManagerImpl` by Guice container. But Guice creates new one instead.

```
GuiceModule mainModule = new GuiceModule();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(mainModule);
Map<Key<?>, Binding<?>> bindings = injector.getAllBindings();
for (Binding<?> binding : bindings.values()) {
  Object instance = injector.getInstance(binding.getKey());
}
```

Below is example of configuration of GuiceModule.

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
         bind(UserManager.class).to(UserManagerImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this binding instead:

```
    bind(UserManagerImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(UserManager.class).to(UserManagerImpl.class);
```

This takes care that `UserManagerImpl` is the real singleton and not the interface. That way calling **both**

```
injector.getInstance(UserManager.class);
injector.getInstance(UserManagerImpl.class);
```

will result in the same instance. By iterating over *all* Bindings and calling `getInstance` on them you also called the later - which was not marked `Singleton` and bingo - you've got several instances.

So....

But if you still must get all singletons due to some other reason: Use a `BindingScopingVisitor` like this:

```
    BindingScopingVisitor<Boolean> visitor = new IsSingletonBindingScopingVisitor();
    Map<Key<?>, Binding<?>> bindings = injector.getAllBindings();
    for (Binding<?> binding : bindings.values()) {
        Key<?> key = binding.getKey();
        System.out.println("Examing key "+ key);

        Boolean foundSingleton = binding.acceptScopingVisitor(visitor);
        if( foundSingleton ) {
            Object instance = injector.getInstance(key);
            System.out.println("\tsingleton: " + instance);
        }
    }

class IsSingletonBindingScopingVisitor implements BindingScopingVisitor<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean visitEagerSingleton() {
        System.out.println("\tfound eager singleton");
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean visitScope(Scope scope) {
        System.out.println("\t scope: "+scope);
        return scope == Scopes.SINGLETON;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean visitScopeAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> scopeAnnotation) {
        System.out.println("\t scope annotation: "+scopeAnnotation);
        return scopeAnnotation == Singleton.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean visitNoScoping() {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Examing key Key[type=com.google.inject.Injector, annotation=[none]]
Examing key Key[type=java.util.logging.Logger, annotation=[none]]
Examing key Key[type=com.google.inject.Stage, annotation=[none]]
    found eager singleton
    singleton: DEVELOPMENT
Examing key Key[type=UserManager, annotation=[none]]
Examing key Key[type=UserManagerImpl, annotation=[none]]
     scope: Scopes.SINGLETON
    singleton: UserManagerImpl@1935d392
```